# Combine CREATE TABLE, ADD COLUMNS, PRIMARY KEY, AS SELECT, and WHERE into one operation

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mariadb

I need to create a copy of a table (if it does not already exist), and this copy needs one of the existing columns to become a primary key.

Currently I have the following SQL commands (in a Python script):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FilteredTable AS SELECT * FROM RawTable WHERE <cond>

ALTER TABLE FilteredTable ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS (NewCol1 TEXT, etc TEXT)

ALTER TABLE FilteredTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (ColumnNameFromRaw)
```

This works fine the first time around, but of course when run again after the table already exists it complains that a primary key already exists.  Is there a way to combine the `ADD PRIMARY KEY` with the `CREATE TABLE ...` command so that it only attempts to set the primary key when the table needs to be created?

*EDIT*
Python code can be used.

**SQL: 10.1.23-MariaDB**
**Python: 2.7**

Comment: It doesn't look like you can do this without using a stored proc and/or some dynamic SQL.  [See here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24531/mysql-create-index-if-not-exists) for some options.

Comment: Darn.  Alright, thanks.  Is there any harm in having that error occur, aside from the cringe factor?

Comment: Actually, if it's failing and not doing anything, with an annoying error message, that's the better outcome IMO.  From what I read, it might actually go and create another index, and you probably wouldn't want that happening in production.

Comment: Yeah the last thing I want is somehow having thousands of primary key instances after years of use...

Comment: `SHOW COLUMNS FROM FilteredTable;` doesn't seem to display anything suspicious...
Should be okay as long as it doesn't prevent my Python script from continuing.

Comment: I think it is better to first check if the table exists `select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema="db_name" and table_name="FilteredTable"` and create primary key only if it does not.

Comment: Thanks for the command, I have thought of something similar...I realized I can do some checking with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extra columns and indexes in the `CREATE TABLE` command even when coming from a `SELECT`.  So do it all in one step:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FilteredTable (
    NewCol1 TEXT, etc TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ColumnNameFromRaw)
) AS SELECT * FROM RawTable WHERE <cond>
```

Note:  the column names are matched up by name.  That is, if `*` has a `NewCol1`, it will go into that `TEXT` column.  If not, then `NewCol1` will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite as clean as a purely SQL solution, but it works in the event that you're accessing SQL indirectly like so...

```
# ...
# (New table creation)
# ...

# Display column data for specified table
curs.execute("SHOW COLUMNS FROM NewTable")
# Collect the data as a tuple of tuples containing chart rows
colsNew = curs.fetchall()
# Iterate through each table column (row in the chart)
for col in colsNew:
    # Check to see if Key is not "PRI" for the Field (Column) "DesiredColumn"
    if (col[0] == "DesiredColumn") and (col[3] != "PRI"):
        # Make DesiredColumn the primary key
        curs.execute("ALTER TABLE NewTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (DesiredColumn)")
```